# Comparing multiple columns in excel

Tags: excel, comparison, excel-formula, vba

I have two excel spreadsheets with 2 columns each. One column is the Unique ID and the other is the Employee's name. Both the spreadsheets are from different sources but must have the same data. I am able to add formulas in excel to check if the unique ID columns match, and to retrieve the ones that are missing in both the sheets.

What I now need to do is, to go through the unique IDs one by one and check if, for the same ID on both the sheets, is the value in the Name column the same ? If not, I need to retrieve the ID's which have discrepancies.

Can this be done with formulas in excel ?

Any help is much appreciated ! Thank you.

Comment: simple vlookup: `=vlookup(id1,..)=name1`? i.e. `=VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet2!A:B,2,0)=B1` where `A1` contaisn ID, `B1` - corresponding name and `Sheet2!A:B` data from second spreadsheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, concatenate the id and name columns to a third column, then run a vlookup on that third column to see if the values in both sheets match. you can use iferror function to return unique id in case vlookup fails to match.